# How to make docker download external file references at initialisation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

new user of docker here, I tried to figured it myself with google but...

I have a nodeJS/express app with this structure :

```
|- modules 
|- lib
|- node_modules : nodejs modules
|- server.js
|- docker-compose.yml
|- dockerfile
```

In the lib directory I have reference files (like for example the geo2ip database : https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ ) that I don't want to include it in my docker image, as it will be huge, and quickly outdated. 
Instead I want my docker image, every it runs to download the last version of the file through an url, so I don't have to build another image every time I need to update this reference file.

I tried to add curl command in the dockerfile like this :

```
CMD curl https://test.com/huge_file.mmdb --output  lib/huge_file.mmdb
```

Or execute shell script, but either it has no effect, either it adds the file to the image, which I don't want.

Any idea how I can ask docker to download a file from the internet, and add it to the container at startup ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do for this case is to mount some external storage into your container.

```
docker run -v $PWD/huge_files:/app/lib ...
```

This causes whatever is in the `huge_files` directory locally to be visible inside the container, replacing what was in the `lib` directory before.

Once you've done this, the easiest thing to do is to just manage this whole process from the host.  Download the files at your convenience; possibly have a shell script to to update the files and start the container.  The advantage of doing this is that you control exactly when it happens; the downside is that it's a manual step.

If you want the container to do it on startup, you can write an entrypoint script to do this.  A Docker [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) is a program that gets run as the main container process; it gets run instead of `CMD`, but it gets passed the `CMD` as arguments.  Frequently an entrypoint will be a shell script that ends by replacing itself with the `CMD`, `exec "$@"`.  You can use this for any first-time setup your container needs:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Download the file if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -f lib/huge_file.mmdb ]; then
  curl https://test.com/huge_file.mmdb --output  lib/huge_file.mmdb
fi

# Switch to the container command
exec "$@"
```

The downside to this approach is potentially doing a large download outside the user's control; if nothing is mounted into the container, potentially repeating the same download on every container startup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer. The ENTRYPOINT command was exactly what I needed !